# Variation of the determinant of a Jacobian

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am following a derivation in a Calculus of Variation problem.
After introducing a one-parameter family of one-to-one mappings from $R^{2}$ to itself, $$z({x},\epsilon)$$, $x = (x_1,x_2)$, such that $$z({x},0) = x$$.
The mapping is used for a change of variable within an integral, hence the issue of computing the variation of the jacobian's determinant arises.
The author says that the obvious identity $$\delta \, det z_{a,b} = \delta z_{a,a}$$

Well as it often happens, it is not entirely obvious to some...Any help would be so appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is $z_{a,a}$ exactly? Please add a reference to the source of the claim. The author could be using some structure of $z$ that you did not include in the post.

Comment: The source is page 39 of the book "Introduction to Micromechanics" by K. Le.Repeated indices summation is used, so the way I read it $z_{a,a} = z_{1,1}+z_{2,2}$, the comma indicated partial derivation.

Comment: $z_{ab}$ is obviously a matrix--we need to know what that matrix is.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Consider a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ [let us write $z=f(x,\epsilon)$] with the property that $f(\cdot , 0)={\rm id}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is the identity map.
2. Define Jacobi matrix $A:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Then $\left. A \right|_{\epsilon=0}={\bf 1}_{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix.
3. One can argue in several ways that the sought-for identity must hold, e.g.
   $$ \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon} \det(A)  \right|_{\epsilon=0}
   ~=~\left. \det(A)^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon} \det(A)  \right|_{\epsilon=0}
   ~=~\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\ln\det(A)  \right|_{\epsilon=0}$$
   $$~=~\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}{\rm tr}\ln(A) \right|_{\epsilon=0}
   ~=~\left.{\rm tr}(A^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}A) \right|_{\epsilon=0}
   ~=~\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}{\rm tr}(A) \right|_{\epsilon=0}. $$

Comment: Qmechanic, thank you very much as usual. I am in the process of deciphering your derivation, as I am still unfamiliar to certain tensorial operations. Let me then try to learn more by checking why I am unable to derive the same by using the definition. Let introduce a variation in $z$ by setting $\hat{z} = z + \epsilon \bar{z}$.

Comment: Qmechanic, thank you very much as usual. I am in the process of deciphering your derivation, as I am still unfamiliar to certain tensorial operations. Let me then try to learn more by checking why I am unable to derive the same by using the definition. stay in $R^2$. Let us introduce a variation in $z$ by setting $\hat{z} = z + \epsilon \bar{z}$. Then the variation of the determinant equals $ \delta \operatorname{det} z_{a,b} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\operatorname{det} \hat{z} - \operatorname{det}{z}}{\epsilon} =$ (To be continued)

Comment: Hi @Buco. You can only edit a comment for 5 minutes but you can delete it anytime. So the trick (for a LaTeX-heavy comment) is to store the comment in an external editor, copy&paste into a new comment, edit for 5 min, delete, open a new comment, edit for 5 min, delete, open a new comment, etc, until you are satisfied with the format of the comment. Alternatively, you can try flag a moderator, but I doubt he would be too enthusiastic about having to clean up other peoples comments.

Comment: @Buco: Hover the mouse over the comment you want to delete. An "x" should appear at the end of the comment. Click on the "x". Bam!

Comment: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\left(z_{1,1}+\epsilon \bar{z}_{1,1}\right)\left(z_{2,2}+\epsilon \bar{z}_{2,2}\right)-\left(z_{1,2}+\epsilon \bar{z}_{1,2}\right)\left(z_{2,1}+\epsilon \bar{z}_{2,1}\right)-\operatorname{det}z_{a,b}}{\epsilon}$$
Simplifying, one gets $$\delta z_{a,b} =\bar{z} _{1,1} z_{ 2,2} +\bar{z}_{ 2,2} z_{ 1,1} −z_{ 1,2} \bar{z} _ {2,1} -z_{2,1} \bar{z}_{  1,2},$$ not the trace.
Where do things go wrong?

Comment: @Buco, I have fixed the formatting on your comment.